# Encoding for serial port communication

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a program that send commands to my serial port.

I've used the following code:

```
my_string6 = "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}".format('P1','130','37','39','0','1','\r\n')
my_string_as_bytes=str.encode(my_string6)
ser.write(my_string_as_bytes)
```

the ouput is the folowing:

```
b'P1 130 37 39 0 1 \r\n'
```

Which is what i'm looking for but my arduino on the other hand doesn't do any action du to the 130 value, it seems like, i can't encode 3 caraters because if i change 130 to 99 for example, my arduino code works great.

Do you have any idea why and if there is a way to encode 3 caracters as this would be very helpfull. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would appear to entirely be an issue at the Arduino end.  Perhaps it simply doesn't support values as high as 130?  Perhaps it's expecting the value in hexadecimal?  NO encoding is going to turn the string `'130'` into anything less than 3 characters...

Comment: Hi Jasonharper, thanks for the comment, i was first thinking about this but i launch the command directily from the serial port of Arduino and the arduino did the job with any value even with 4 caracters. that is why i thought the problem came from encoding. any other idea? Thanks